# obtaining the sum of items in one wx listctrl column

Tags: python, wxpython

So I have this listctrl here

```
self.list2 = wx.ListCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( -1,100 ), wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_SORT_DESCENDING )
            self.list2.InsertColumn(0,"Order ID")
            self.list2.InsertColumn(1,"Item ID")
            self.list2.InsertColumn(2,"Item Price")
            self.list2.InsertColumn(3,"Item Qty")
            self.list2.Bind(EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED,self.GetSelectedItems2)
            self.list2.Bind(EVT_LIST_DELETE_ITEM,self.delete_item)
```

right now, I'm trying to come up with a function that will Iterate through the given list and get the sum of all the item prices in said list... I got no ideas on how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have prices of some kind in the Item Price column this ought to do it:

```
total = sum(float(self.GetItem(row, 2).GetText()) for row in range(self.GetItemCount()))
```

Comment: Actually, you should use the decimal module for summing dollar amounts, not float. Otherwise you'll probably have rounding issues.